# tkinter button double use

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new here and new in PY, I'm trying to write a simple GUI with Tkinter (py 2.7.10) where there are two buttons: the first one starts printing stuff and the second one quits.
I'd like the first button to change the text after the first click from "START" to "STOP" and of course to stop the loop, so I can pause instead of closing and reopen every time.

Also feel free to give any advice to improve it :)

I hope it's clear, here is the code.

```
import random, time
from Tkinter import *

START, STOP = "start", "stop"

class AppBase:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.myRoot = root
        self.frame1 = Frame(root)
        self.frame1["background"] = "LightSteelBlue"
        self.frame1.pack()

        self.delay = Scale(self.frame1, from_=100, to=0)
        self.delay.pack(side = LEFT, padx=5, pady=15)

        self.label0 = Label(self.frame1, text="Notes", background="LightSteelBlue", foreground="darkblue")
        self.label0.pack(padx=5, pady=15)
        self.label1 = Label(self.frame1, text="NOTE", background="LightSteelBlue", foreground="SteelBlue")
        self.label1.pack(padx=30, pady=10)
        self.label2 = Label(self.frame1, text="STRING", background="LightSteelBlue", foreground="SteelBlue")
        self.label2.pack(padx=30, pady=7)
        self.label3 = Label(self.frame1, text="FINGER", background="LightSteelBlue", foreground="SteelBlue")
        self.label3.pack(padx=30, pady=7)

        self.puls1 = Button(self.frame1)
        self.puls1.configure(text = "Start", background = "CadetBlue", borderwidth = 3, command = self.generate_notes)
        self.puls1.pack(side = LEFT, padx=5, pady=15)
        self.puls2 = Button(self.frame1)
        self.puls2.configure(text = "Exit", background = "CadetBlue", borderwidth = 3)
        self.puls2.pack(side = LEFT, padx=5, pady=15)
        self.puls2.bind("<Button-1>", self.close_all)
        self.notes_process=1

    def generate_notes(self):
        self.notes = ['DO','DO#','RE','RE#','MI','MI#','FA','FA#','SOL','SOL#','LA','LA#','SI','SI#']
        self.strings = ['1^ corda','2^ corda','3^ corda','4^ corda','5^ corda','6^ corda']
        self.fingers = ['Indice','Medio','Anulare','Mignolo']
        self.note = random.randrange(0, len(self.notes))
        self.string = random.randrange(0, len(self.strings))
        self.finger = random.randrange(0, len(self.fingers))
        self.timer=self.delay.get()
        if self.timer == '':
            self.timer = 500
        elif int(self.timer) < 1:
            self.timer = 500
        else:
            self.timer=int(self.delay.get())*100
        self.label1["text"] = self.notes[self.note]
        self.label2["text"] = self.strings[self.string]
        self.label3["text"] = self.fingers[self.finger]
        self.myRoot.after(self.timer, self.generate_notes)

    def close_all(self, evento):
        self.myRoot.destroy()
        self.myRoot.quit()

def main():
    master = Tk()
    master.title("Notes")
    appBase = AppBase(master)
    master.mainloop()

main()
```

---

I found a solution, thanks to everybody for their help and of course if you want to keep talking about different and (sure) better way to do, you are more than welcome!
Here my solution:

step 1, add this to the button:
`self.puls1.bind("<Button-1>", self.puls1Press1)`

step 2, add a new variable:
    `self.active = True`

step 3, create a new function:

```
def puls1Press1(self, evento):
    if self.puls1["text"] == "Start":
        self.puls1["text"] = "Stop"
        self.active = True
    else:
        self.puls1["text"] = "Start"
        self.active = False
```

step 4, modify the function that I want to stop:

```
def generate_notes(self):
    if self.active == True:
        [some code]
        [some code]
    else:
        return
```

Comment: I found a solution, thanks to everybody for their help and of course if you want to keep talking about different and (sure) better way to do, you are more than welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to save the return value of the `after`, so that you can use it when you cancel the loop using [`after_cancel(the_return_value_of_after)`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after_cancel-method).

```
def generate_notes(self):
    if self.puls1['text'] == 'Start':
        # Change button text to Stop, and call the original loop function
        self.puls1['text'] = 'Stop'
        self._generate_notes()
    else:
        # cancel timer
        self.puls1['text'] = 'Start'
        self.myRoot.after_cancel(self.timer_handle)

def _generate_notes(self):
    ...(old codes)..
    self.timer_handle = self.myRoot.after(self.timer, self._generate_notes)
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it behaves in the exactly same way as before. But I found another way to fix it, I'll write in another post. Thank you.

Comment: @Saw, It worked for me. FYI, here's the full code I tried: http://pastebin.com/iWLKBUCV

Comment: I spent one hour but I found out that the text editor that I use under Ubuntu (Geany) doesn't work if I use the TAB button to indentate the code. Now, once I changed every TAB with 4 spaces it works :) - Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

`StringVar()` from variable class can be used to update text as well as a looping condition. Example code:

```
ButtonText=StringVar()
ButtonText.set("START")
button1 = tkinter.Button(self.frame1, text=ButtonText, width=25, command= lambda: do_something(ButtonText))
```

Elsewhere where you are looping check for the value of the variable:

```
My_Loop():
    if(ButtonText.get()=="STOP"):
         break
    else:
        #some print statements
```

Now in function `do_something(ButtonText)`, which will be called after each button press, change the string to "STOP" or vice versa :

```
do_something(ButtonText):
    if(ButtonText.get()=="START): #Change text
          ButtonText.set("STOP")
    else:
          ButtonText.set("START") #Change text and call function to loop again
          My_Loop()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Too complicated I need time to understand, but I found a work around and I'll post here to show my solution, thank you very.